# Add multiple Groups to IAM User using AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

This command works fine with one group:

```
aws iam add-user-to-group --user-name user1 --group-name group1
```

Now need to add multiple groups to user while creating like:

```
aws iam add-user-to-group --user-name user1 --group-name group1 group2
```

How could this achieved?

Comment: Note: to get help on awscli commands, run: `aws <service> help` or `aws <service> <command> help`, for example `aws iam add-user-to-group help`.

Answer (score 2):

The `add-user-to-group` command only allows one group to be added to a user at a time.

You would either need to call that command multiple times, or you could write code using an AWS SDK and add your own logic to add multiple groups.